# How did football become so popular in Latin America, but not in anglophone North America?

Tags: football, history

It would be very interesting to know why football failed to achieve higher recognition despite the expanse of the British colonists in anglophone North America, being the [4-5th most popular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sports_in_the_United_States#Overview) team sport there, as compared to Latin America where [football is considered a religion](https://sites.duke.edu/wcwp/2015/02/06/the-role-of-soccer-in-latin-american-culture/), again despite little to no influence of Brits over Latin America.

(The more popular sports being American football, Baseball, Basketball and Ice hockey when considering Canada. All of them originated in North America.)

Comment: Too broad or POB? I flipped a coin. VTC.

Comment: @Nij, I think historical facts should not be opinion based.

Comment: "Should" is not a great word for describing things that are "considered a religion".

Comment: It would be nice to see some comments here from down and closevoters, maybe explaining what can be improved.

Comment: How much more do you want? It's patently too broad, and a significant or majority part is necessarily opinion.

Comment: Any opinions from others too :)